# Error when "Cancel" while opening a file in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a simple PyQt4 GUI where I have the user open a txt file that will display in the GUI's QPlainTextEdit widget. 
Here's the pseudo code:

```
class mainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.plain = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.openButton = QtGui.QPushButton("OPEN")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.plain)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.openButton)
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

    def openFile(self):
        openFileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File","/some/dir/","TXT(*.txt);;AllFiles(*.*)")
        openFile = open(openFileName,'r').read()
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(openFile)
```

So I click the "OPEN" button and the QFileDialog pops up, but if I hit the "CANCEL" button within the QFileDialog, I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'')
```

I know as the programmer that this error can be easily ignored and does not impact the code's operation whatsoever, but the users do not know that. Is there a way to eliminate this error from printing in terminal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes: simply check the return value from [`getOpenFileName`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName).  This method returns an empty `QString` if the user clicks Cancel.  As empty `QString`s are considered false, you can check to see if the user chose a file instead of clicking Cancel by putting the last two lines of your `openFile` method in an `if openFileName:` statement:

```
    def openFile(self):
        openFileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File","/some/dir/","TXT(*.txt);;AllFiles(*.*)")
        if openFileName:
            openFile = open(openFileName,'r').read()
            self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(openFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

as one above said, you should debug and check what kind of answer "openFilename" returns.

in Pyqt5, when you press cancel or 'x' to close the window, it returns a tuple

so to get around the issue:

```
openFileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
if openFileName != ('', ''):
    with open(openFileName [0], 'r') as f:
        file_text = f.read()
        self.text.setText(file_text)
```